# Route react app to error.html file on wrong path url entries

Tags: reactjs, server, react-router, hosting

I am hosting a react app / landing page on a static hosting service similar to S3 by AWS. Its Ionos by 1&1 . I want to set the error.html so that it routes to my main component or if that isn't doable to an error.html which ideally points back to my react app.

Main goal is to not have a blank page when a wrong path / url is entered. I am using react router and its not an isomorphic app.

I am unaware what kind of http server the hosting service is running on and I cannot change the configuration of that server, but apparently there is a way to set an error.html via a dedicated html file in the project folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Error 404</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Ops, page does not exist</h3>
<p><a href="index.html">To the main page</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

If I do this, I could set an href back to my react app, but thats an ugly setup. One solution that came to my mind was to host a "clone" of the react app in error.html but that would be just as bad. Any ideas how to set an error.html file that leads back to my main app if its not an isomorphic one?